# Sum a non adjacent region possible containing NULL values in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to sum `C11+E11+H11+I11`, where if for instance `C11` is NULL I want the sum of `E11+H11+I11`.

If the region were adjacent, for instance if I were to sum the region `C11:E11` I would be able to do:

`SUMIF(C11:E11,"<>",C11:E11)`

I don't know how to translate that formula into my current instance, where the region to be summed is non-adjacent.

Does somebody have a clue?

Comment: SUM ignores any text or nulls within the range, so simply =SUM(C11,E11,H11,I11) should be fine for you.

Comment: @XOR LX        Aah, the wonders of Excel! Adapting the formula from "`C11+E11+H11+T11` to `SUM(C11;E11;H11;T11)` did indeed give me the correct answer. Please consider posting your comment as an answer and I will Accept it.

Comment: Done. Yes - some subtle differences between addition performed using the SUM function and that performed via use of the plus operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SUM` ignores any text or nulls within the range, so simply:

`=SUM(C11,E11,H11,I11)`

should be fine for you.

Regards